# How can I view all information from my facebook social plugins in one place?

Tags: facebook, plugin

I am using some [Facebook social plugins](http://developers.facebook.com/plugins) on one of my websites that has hundreds of pages. I am wondering if there is a single location where I can view all Facebook plugin activity across my website.

Is there some sort of admin page where I can find that info?

**EDIT:** I am using the Comments Plugin and the Like Button. I would like to be able to see all the comments on my website in one 'dashboard' rather than having to browse to each individual page on my website and administer the comments there.

Comment: What kind of information, exactly?

Comment: this question should be titled "frist!!1"

Comment: Yeah I can't believe I got the 1st question in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure if Facebook provides this for you but they do provide some tools so that you could build it for yourself. Take a look at the [FB.Event.Subscribe](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe) method in their JavaScript SDK. Using that you could subscribe to Like and Comment and record the info off on your own dashboard. Not an easy solution, but it could get the job done.

Comment: Yeah I am beginning to feel like you're right about this. I was hoping to not have to avoid it. Thanks for your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

This page gives an easy answer
http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-ultimate-guide-to-implementing-facebook-comments-on-your-blog/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.